# Strange DB2 JPA sequence generation

Tags: spring, jpa, db2, eclipselink, sequence

I found the sequences in my JPA project using eclipselink, spring and db were not generated continuously. JPA seems retrieve the next cached sequence numbers even the current sequence numbers don't run up.

my sequence is created by this statement

```
create or replace sequence MYSCHEMA.SEQ_MY_ID
as integer
  start with 1 increment by 1;
```

and the cache of the sequence is 20.

My application will need two sequence numbers for MY_ID column each run. What I expect is the sequence like this:

```
RUN #1
1
2
RUN #2
3
4
```

But actually the sequence numbers generated like this:

```
RUN #1
1
21
RUN #2
2
3
RUN #3
22
41
```

There are two threads running at the same time to request the sequence. But the sequence should be generated continuously even though in multi-thread environment. Why the next cached value is used? How can I figure out what is culprit? DB2, JPA, or Spring.

Answer (score 1):

Use the NO CACHE option when you create your sequence and there will be no gaps.  Be aware that performance will be slightly worse.

Answer (score 1):

I general I would recommend using an increment and allocationSize to allow ids to be preallocated.  This will drastically improve performance.  Not sure why you don't want holes, but if this is a real requirement, then you will need to remove your cache option in addition to your increment.

Answer (score 0):

DB2 sequences have option called "ORDER/NO ORDER" and the default is "NO ORDER". I guess this is the reason, but I haven't the time to test it. Will post it after testing.